# Make the legend that auto wrap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've developped a plugin in QGIS which can generate some maps automatically. But, for certains legend's entry the text is too large for the block. It it possible in QGIS (python) to wrap legend's text? Not with a caracter, but automatically?